Edwards curve example
I am looking to deepen my understanding of Edwards elliptic curves, specifically focusing on addition operations. Could anyone recommend books or websites that provide detailed examples with numerical calculations for adding points on Edwards elliptic curves? I am interested in examples using affine coordinates, projective coordinates, or any other coordinate systems.
Additionally, how can I ensure the correctness of my calculations when performing these operations? Are there any established methods or tools for verifying the accuracy of these computations?

https://sefiks.com/2018/12/19/a-gentle-introduction-to-edwards-curves/

Although we don't have an explicit close reason for Q's like these, they may be closed for the reason of being "opinionated". There is not one single answer possible and it is unclear when the question would be sufficiently answered.
